# How can I model this data in a er model

Tags: database-design

## This is the description

- This is a LMS system
- There are Batches which have Grade, Medium, Syllabus and Year.
- There are Tutors who can teach a Specific Subject.
- The Subject has Grade, Medium, and Syllabus.
- There are Classes for The Batch which a Tutor teaches and The Class has a subject. The Class can happen on multiple days of the week with a time slot like start time and end time.
- The Student is enrolled to the Class and attends the Class on a recurring basis.
- How can I create an er model to facilitate this Class and Batch structure?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sounds like homework ...... what have you attempted so far?

Comment: i have created the er